# ¿Como puedo alinear un video a la izquierda y dos lineas de texto una debajo de la otra?

Tags: html, css

¿Cómo puedo hacer que un video que está en la izquierda se alinee con dos lineas de texto uno debajo del otro en HTML y luego, hacerlo también por CSS?

Este es el código que tengo:

```css
.COVID{
    text-align: center;
}
#videocovid{
    text-align: left;
}
#textosalut{
    text-align: right;
}
#videocovid{
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
}
#fotoscovid{
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<section class="COVID">
    <h1> COVID 19</h1>
    <div id="videocovid">
        <video width="600px" controls autoplay>
            <source src="img/Hospital.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
    </div>

    <div id="textosalut">
        <a href="https://canalsalut.gencat.cat/ca/salut-a-z/c/coronavirus-2019-ncov/">Canal Salut Generalitat</a>
    </div>
    <div id="fotoscovid">
        <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/hospitalesperitsant/albums/72157713801612566">Recull Fotos Crisis Sanitaria</a>   
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: ¿Cuáles son las 2 líneas de texto?

Comment: son los div llamados textosalut y fotoscovid

Comment: Yo también publiqué una respuesta de lo que logré entender...

Comment: Muchas Gracias por las respuestas

Answer (score 1):

Un placer saludarte.

Lo que hice con bootstrap fue esto:

```html
<section class="COVID">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6 col-md-6">
               <h1> COVID 19</h1>
               <div id="videocovid">
                    <video width="600px" controls autoplay>
                        <source src="img/Hospital.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                        </video>
                    </div>
                    <div id="textosalut">
                         <a href="https://canalsalut.gencat.cat/ca/salut-a-z/c/coronavirus-2019-ncov/">Canal Salut Generalitat</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="fotoscovid">
                       <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/hospitalesperitsant/albums/72157713801612566">Recull Fotos Crisis Sanitaria</a>   
                    </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-6 col-md-6">
                   <h1>Otra sección</h1>
               </div>
      </div>
 </section>
```

Y se visualiza así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Allí esta sin tu CSS.

Y así lo hice solo con CSS:

```html
<section class="COVID">
      <div class="fila" style="display:flex;">
           <div class="columna_1" style="width:30%">
                <h1> COVID 19</h1>
                <div id="videocovid">
                     <video width="100%" controls autoplay>
                         <source src="img/Hospital.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                         <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                              Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                     </video>
                </div>
           <div id="textosalut">
                <a href="https://canalsalut.gencat.cat/ca/salut-a-z/c/coronavirus-2019-ncov/">Canal Salut Generalitat</a>
           </div>
           <div id="fotoscovid">
               <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/hospitalesperitsant/albums/72157713801612566">Recull Fotos Crisis Sanitaria</a>   
              </div>
         </div>
         <div class="columna_2" style="width:70%">
              <h1>Otra sección</h1>
         </div>
     </div>
 </section>
```

Y me quedó así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta imagen, el video lo pasé de 600px a 100% para que se adapte a la capa que lo contiene la cual la deja al 30% y para el contenido, esa capa la deje al 70%.

Espero te sirva.

Ha sido un placer.

Answer (score 0):

Código propuesto:

```html
    <style>
      .covid-contenido {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
    </style>

    <section class="COVID">
        <h1> COVID 19</h1>
          <div class="covid-contenido">
            <div id="videocovid">
              <video width="600px" controls autoplay>
                  <source src="img/Hospital.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
              </video>
            </div>

            <div class="textos">
              <div id="textosalut">
                <a href="https://canalsalut.gencat.cat/ca/salut-a-z/c/coronavirus-2019-ncov/">Canal Salut Generalitat</a>
              </div>
              <div id="fotoscovid">
                <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/hospitalesperitsant/albums/72157713801612566">Recull Fotos Crisis Sanitaria</a>   
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </section>
```

Comentarios:

- Puedes apoyarte de [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox) para conseguir el resultado que buscas
- Movemos los divs que contienen texto a un div que los agrupe
- Movemos dentro de un div contenedor tanto al video como al div que contiene a los textos
- Dejamos por fuera del contenedor de los elementos anteriores a la etiqueta h1
- Dejar a los textos dentro de un div generará que permanezcan uno abajo del otro